# Proof of $⊢ψ↔φ⇒ (⊢θ⇒ ⊢θ[φ/ψ])$

Tags: logic

I can prove the caption result (i.e. $⊢ψ↔φ⇒ (⊢θ ⇒ ⊢θ[φ/ψ])$ by making arguments about derivations i.e. if I create a new derivation with the derivation for $ψ↔φ$ at the front and then add the lines in the old derivation of $⊢θ$ by swapping out the $ψ$'s for $φ$'s in a special (selective) way (plus some other rules).

It's rather a lengthy argument, especially since I am doing so in the context of natural deduction. I am wondering if I am overlooking a more baisc approach? Does anyone have a simple proof for this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show $\vdash (\psi \iff \phi) \implies (\theta \iff \theta[\phi / \psi])$. You can this by a straightforward structural induction on $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks. It works! A lot simplier than the method I was using.